# how to create dynamically text view with checkbox according to list of data

Tags: flutter

[image]

This layout has made in android and this text view with checkbox created dynamically according to the list of data. but I want this same screen enter code here` make in flutter but it showing error this,(right text overflowed by 10.0 pixel), and I have to share my flutter code and screen also.how to fix it(or this same screen can be made another way then).
Please suggest to me.  [image]

This is my flutter screen and code here.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());



 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Checked Listview',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Checked Listview'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      List<String> _list = [];
      List<String> _listString = ["Ac","Fuel Sensor","Power","Panic","Camera","Relay","Duty 
         Button","Other"];
      List<bool> inputs = List<bool>();
      var singleline;
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        setState(() {
          for (int i = 0; i < _listString.length; i++) {
            _list.insert(0, '${_listString[i]}');
          }
        });
      }
    
      void ItemChange(bool val,int index){
        setState(() {
          inputs[index] = val;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Checked Listview'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              _list.isNotEmpty
                  ? Wrap(
                children: _list
                    .map(
                      (item) => IntrinsicWidth(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 120,
                      height: 40,
                      child: Card(
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Center(
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Checkbox(value: false,
                                      onChanged:(bool val){}
                                  ),
                            Text(item),
                                ],
                              ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                    .toList(),
              )
               : Container(
                child: Text(
                 "Empty",
                   maxLines: 2,
                   style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 16.0,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                   color: Colors.black),
                    )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: you can use gridview

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by simply using `Expanded` as it follows:

```
children: <Widget>[
  Checkbox(
    value: false,
    onChanged: (bool val) {},
  ),
 Expanded(child: Text(item)),
],
```

This is the result:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the behavior you wish to achieve is moving the text to a second line if it overflows.

I recommend using the [`AutoSizeText`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package to do this.

For example,

```
AutoSizeText(
'sample_text', 
 maxLines: 2,
 style: ...
)
```

The above code will directly move the overflowed text to a second line.